# Sum of all integer divisors of a number

Tags: c++, loops, integer-division

I want to find sum of all divisors of a number i.e. if the number is 6 i want to have 1+2+3+6=12. My attempt to approach it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int divisorsSum(int n){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(n%i==0)
            i=sum+i;

    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<divisorsSum(6);
}
```

However surprisingly it does not work at all, it returns nothing and i am not able to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Thus the question is how to make it works? 
BTW: There is no point in immediately down voting everything I am not an expert and yes i do make mistakes.

Comment: `i=sum+i;` should be `sum=sum+i` or even better `sum += i;`.

Comment: Where in that function do you change `sum`?

Comment: pretty sure you mean `i=1` for your for loop and `sum += i;` after the if.  Next time be more careful when copying the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

```
int i = i;
```

and `i` is still not defined. You probably wanted `i = 1`

```
i = sum + i;
```

sum is not updated above. You probably wanted `sum += i`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your function `divisorsSum` to use the following code:

```
int divisorsSum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=i; i<=n; i++)
```

Change the i=i to i = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
int divisorsSum(int n){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
         if(n%i==0)
            sum+=i;

    }
return sum;
}
```

1. i starts from 1 and not i
2. sum+=i and not i=sum+i

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better algorithms of finding divisors of a number, but here is the correct version of your code.

```
int divisorsSum(int n){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
       if(n % i == 0)
            sum += i;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

And here is a little optimized version, if a `i` is bigger than half of `n` then `i` cannot be a divisor of `n`.

```
int divisorsSum(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; --i){
       if(n % i == 0)
            sum += i;

    }
    return sum;
}
```